# how to create scene in Autodesk viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

when you upload a model into Autodesk web viewer it shows you a side panel name scenes (or views), i want to know how should i create a scene for my 3d model to be present there?

i tried to create different views in Autodesk inventor for an assembly model and also different scenes for Autodesk inventor presentation file and uploaded them into Autodesk viewer but no success.
how can i create deferent scenes for Autodesk Viewer?
actually, i want to apply different textures to different scenes

Answer (score 1):

It is true that the Autodesk Forge [Model Derivative APIs](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2) can generate multiple "viewables" for certain input file formats, for example, a single Revit file could generate multiple 3D views and 2D sheets. Unfortunately, I don't think the APIs support multiple viewables from Inventor files. You would have to create multiple Inventor files, modify them (either manually or using the new [Design Automation APIs](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v2/developers_guide/overview)), and translate them individually.